# Pushing to Docker Private Organization Repository

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Trying to push an image to a new organization private repository on dockerhub but it keeps giving me an error:

```
unauthorized: authentication required
```

I am the owner of the organization repository and have tried to do changes to teams, permissions etc but cannot get around this

Command being used to push:

```
docker push organization/repo-name:tag
```

I have run docker login and logged in as a user that has the permissions to the repo

Flummoxed and cant find answers anywhere

Comment: Are you mixing sudo with no-sudo docker commands?

Comment: I dont think so. Not used sudo for anything

Comment: Could it be anything due to image size? Does that have an effect?

Comment: `docker login` leaves the credentials in `~/. docker`, do you have something there?

Comment: Yes. I just tried a different image to a different repo and that works. Is there something that could be within an image that would prevent it being pushed?

Comment: I believe you have incorrect permissions, then.

Comment: For what it is worth, I do not think there can be anything with an image that prevents pushing. In most cases, the organization/repo-name:tag turns out to be wrong somehow so it tries to push to another repo that you do not have access to. So try to double check it.

Comment: @OllyW wre you able to solve it? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that your Docker Hub user was recently given write access to the repo or organization and that you need to get a new token by logging out and back in with:

```sh
$ docker logout
Removing login credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/

$ docker login
Username:
Password:
Login Succeeded
```

I ran into the same issue and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what caused the issue but ran via a newly built lubuntu VM using the exact same files and this worked fine.

Was originally used docker via Mac; not sure if that had some influence

But now it has uploaded without further issue